# magento get attribute value for multi select attibute

Tags: attributes, multiselect-attribute

i want to get attribute value for multi select attribute,

below is code that work if it is just text field or drop down , but for multi select it does not work ,
please guide way to fix it

```
$_product->getMetal();
```

works for text attibute for not for multiselect attibutes.

I am using above code on product listing page.

sample snap from where $_product comes:

```
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
```

Comment: Use this code also $_product->getData('attribute_code_here');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you what you need

```
$_product->getAttributeText('attribute_code_here');
```

If you are using this from a collection, make sure the attribute you use is marked as "Used in product listing" and that you rebuilt the indexes.

Comment: it does not give any output , metal is multiselect dropdown attribute , and using this code on product listing page

Comment: but does `$_product->getMetal()` output something?

Comment: no but $_product->getPrice() and weight works fine

Comment: in this case, it depends on the context. If `$_product` comes from a product collection, maybe the attribute `metal` is not added to the collection. You should add more info in your question. Provide the context that uses this.

Comment: added that code is used on product listing page

Comment: See my edit. Maybe it helps.